# Change Windows 7 login screen to Classic XP Style

Tags: windows-7, authentication, domain-controller, login

I was wondering if there is a way to configure windows 7 to use the xp style domain login. User Name, Password and select local machine or domain?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Microsoft completely rewrote the logon screen as of Vista, as well as the entire logon process. With XP and earlier it was possible for third parties to provide their own logon screens through something called a GINA (Graphical Identification and Authentication), and enterprising workplaces had been known to customize it just to make it extra clear that this was a Company computer you were logging in to. Instead of a Microsoft logo, you got a company logo, and other tweaks.

Novell did just this in order to allow Windows to log in to both AD and eDirectory environments from the same login screen while allowing you to specify which eDir tree you wanted to connect to. Some two-factor-authentication providers replaced the GINA with something that would allow the second factor to be provided at login (MS had hooks for this as early as Win2K, but some companies preferred to roll their own with a custom GINA). Various off-the-shelf Kiosk-computer packages also used this method to lock things down.

This level of customization is no longer possible, Microsoft removed it as a security improvement. It is no longer possible for malware to drop in a custom GINA to gain control of the domain login process. There was a lot of complaint coming from companies doing the upgrade to Vista (and later Win7) as a result of this, since the user-experience changes so drastically, but Microsoft was clear: Get used to it, we're not changing it.

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry.  The logon screen was redesigned in Vista and the new design was carried over to 7.

Comment: I did find a semi-answer (http://windows7themes.net/enable-classic-logon-screen-in-windows-7.html).  But in short, no, you cannot use the XP-style logon screen.

Comment: That’s what I was afraid of I will just use the .\"username" option thank you!